# After enabling mouse in tmux(3.0a), How to use it to switch Pane or windows. I am using Conemu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux

I have enabled mouse option setting in conemu(version 220807 64 alpha) as well as on tmux(3.0a on remote system with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) but still not able to switch Panes or Windows with it.
If I use Mosh in the chrome secure shell extension then I can able to use the mouse for all activities but the issue is Mosh everytime open a new window and not a new tab and I am used to Conemu.
So kindly please suggest if anyone using it or used it or knows how to make it work over this combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConEmu (e.g. 220807 [64]) does not support mouse click within tmux, for that use Mobaxterm, windows terminal or Secure shell chrome extension to connect to remote machine and use tmux. Mouse click,pane-resize within tmux is working for these 3.